# How to set default autoincrement value for exponential function

Tags: omnet++

I want to set default auto increment value for exponential function. For example, I want mean arrival rate will be incremented from `exponential(0.01s)` to `exponential(1s)` with step 0.01?

Would anyone suggest how to code that in OMNet++?

Thank you.

Comment: U can try see too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28897535/record-non-scalar-parameter-in-omnet

This looks like a similar problem

Comment: Thank you. But it's not exactly same. For my question will ```exponential(${interval = 0.01..1 step 0.01}s)``` work?